# Error when execute sudo vi /etc/modules

Tags: raspbian, modules, mpu6050

I am following this [tutorial](http://blog.bitify.co.uk/2013/11/interfacing-raspberry-pi-and-mpu-6050.html)

I want to enable I2C feature on Raspi2.

I need to write some line on modules.conf (.conf ? I don't remember the extension).

But executing

> sudo vi /etc/modules

on terminal gives me error. It is like error when a commend is running on terminal but has not finished yet and you are typing. 
When you press Up and Down button on keyboard, the monitor shows A and B respectively.

After I unable to add some line on the file, I press ctrl-Z.
executing the same command again will make terminal tell me that swap file has been created.

anyone can help?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you show it, or take a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vi can be a little hard and confusing for non experienced users.
try to edit the file with nano. its pretty easy to use and would fit your needs.

so type

sudo nano /etc/modules

if nano is not installed install it with the following command.

sudo apt-get install nano

the navigation on nano is pretty similar like on a gui text editor like gedit or windows notepad.

make your changes and safe the file with STRG + X
finally type Y to confirm saving.

Comment: Thank you! I spent like 6 hours figuring what went wrong, like rewrite the 2 different version of image.

Comment: your welcome... i remember times when i had same issues with vi :-)